# Is it correct to clone an instance and keep it stopped instead of making a snapshot?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've noticed that Compute Engine will bill you every Snapshot, but not for having a stopped instance. So, it would be correct to clone an entire instance instead of making a snapshot?

Is there any contraindication, limitation or adverse effect by doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still being billed for the persistent disk space when stopping an instance. The cost for standard persistent disk is $0.04 per GB while snapshot storage will cost you $0.026 so you will actually pay more when stopping an instance compared to using snapshots.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand that unused disks were billed same way that others. So, when I need to stop an instance for a long time, it would be convenient to make a snapshot and delete the instance, and then re-create it when I need it.